# NotAllowedException when reading feeds on the client

Tags: javascript, python, getstream-io

Hi I'm new to GetStream and still learning. Here is a condensed version of what I'm using.

I have a python backend where I create user tokens:

```
client = stream.connect(...)
token = client.create_user_token(id)
return token
```

I then pass the token to the js frontend where it's used to retrieve feed activities for that user. I'm using the normal stream-js client and Jinja for the token and collection.id:

```
const client = stream.connect('apiKey', null, 'appID');
const collection = client.feed('collection', '{{ collection.id }}', '{{ token }}')
request = collection.get({ limit:10})
request.then((data) => {
   ...
)}
```

Here is my problem:
When I request activities for collection:4 everything works as would be expected. But when I do the exact same thing for collection:5 it suddenly gives 
*"You do not have permission to do this, you got this error because there are no policies allowing this request on this application." 403 NotAllowedException*. 
This only happens client-side, server-side it works fine. Could there be a problem in the jwt token used for authentication? 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, users can read their own feeds on the client side.

`collection:4` is working because probably token is generated for the user with id 4 and it fails with permission error when that token is used for `collection:5`.

To have required policies in your app, please contact [support](https://getstream.io/support) with your app details and required policies/feed groups.

Comment: So the jwt tokens that are created are not for the actual *users* of my application, ie users that are registered with Stream. They are tokens for each individual feed? When I created the token with id 5 it worked. Thank you

Comment: 3 hours and finally I found this topic :D

Comment: @lacas ahh, I am sorry you need to go through this. If you have anything, just a new question. We try to monitor and reply as much as possible.

Comment: @ferhatelmas I mailed to you with my problemes.